# Naming amitriptyline by IUPAC

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Can someone guide me through step by step how amitriptyline is named by IUPAC?
I know the name *per se*, but it is very confusing to me, and I'd like someone to explain it to me. The systematic name is

> 3-(10,11-Dihydro-5*H*-dibenzo[a,d]cycloheptene-5-ylidene)-*N,N*-dimethylpropan-1-amine.

Comment: Please note that the fusion nomenclature of the name “3-(10,11-dihydro-5H-dibenzo[a,d]cycloheptene-5-ylidene)-N,N-dimethylpropan-1-amine” corresponds to obsolete IUPAC recommendations from 1979 and is no longer encouraged since 1993. According to the current IUPAC recommendations from 2013, the preferred name is “3-(10,11-dihydro-5H-dibenzo[a,d][7]annulen-5-ylidene)-N,N-dimethylpropan-1-amine”.

Comment: @Loong *[7]annulen* sounds a lot better than *cycloheptene*, because it doesn’t make me think incorrectly that there be only one double bond in cycloheptene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** As stated in a comment to the question by Loong, the preferred IUPAC name according to the 2013 nomenclature recommendations is:

> 3-(10,11-dihydro-5*H*-dibenzo[a,d][7]annulen-5-ylidene)-*N,N*-dimethylpropan-1-amin‌​e

The only change this makes to the analysis it that we can ignore the ‘incorrect’ cycloheptene, because [7]annulen is automatically a cycloheptatriene-type molecule.

---

First, let’s separate the name into its fragments. We have:

1. 3-*something*-propane-1-amine
2. *N,N*-dimethyl
3. (10,11-dihydro-*something*)
4. (*something*-5*H*-dibenzo[a,d]cycloheptene-*something*)
5. (*something*-5-ylidene)

I’m going to start with item 4, since that is the main bicycle. Cycloheptene sounds like this molecule:

[image: Cycloheptene with IUPAC-numbering]

But the [a,d] and the *dibenzo* is telling us that we have a fused polycyclic unsaturated hydrocarbon, so we will need to add two more double bonds. (Skipping a picture of this step.) *Dibenzo* means that there are two fused benzene rings, and the letters in square brackets symbolise the attachment points. *a* stands for 1,2; d for 4,5 (analogously for other letters). With that, we get a tricyclic compound with many double bonds. However, it is still ambiguous *how* exactly to place the double bonds, we need the information 5*H* — it tells us that the ‘additional’ hydrogen must be at the 5-position. **Beware:** The 5-position *does not* reference the initial numbering we used for fusing the rings; the atoms are renumbered according to the rules for aromatic polycycles: Starting at the top right and going clockwise, *ignoring all bridgehead atoms.* So we get 5*H*-dibenzo[a,d]cycloheptene which looks like this:

[image: 5H-dibenzo[a,d]cycloheptene]

Next up, item 3: 10,11-dihydro. This means that the double bond in the seven-membered ring is hydrated, i.e. there is a single bond instead.

[image: 10,11-dihydro-5H-dibenzo[a,d]cycloheptene]

And finally, item 5: 5-ylidene. We are attaching something to carbon 5 *via* a double bond. We’ll get back to that.

Item 1: 3-*something*-propane-1-amine. That’s nice and simple, we’ll first consider propane-1-amine:

[image: propane-1-amine]

*N,N*-dimethyl (item 2) tells us that there are two methyl groups attached to the nitrogen, giving us the following:

[image: N,N-dimethylpropane-1-amine]

And now we need to add the entire tricyclo-blurb to the propane’s 3-position using a double bond:

[image: amitriptyline]

And voilà, there is amitriptylene!

Comment: Wonderful! Very detailed and accurate, and quick response. I'm very thankful :)